# Simplify $A=\frac{y^\frac12}{y^\frac12-2}+\frac{y^\frac12}{y^\frac12+2}-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, rational-numbers

Simplify $$A=\dfrac{y^\frac12}{y^\frac12-2}+\dfrac{y^\frac12}{y^\frac12+2}-2$$ So $$A=\dfrac{y^\frac12\left(y^\frac12+2\right)+y^\frac12\left(y^\frac12-2\right)}{y-4}-2=\dfrac{2y^\frac14}{y-4}-2=\dfrac{2y^\frac14-2y+8}{y-4}$$
Can we simplify further?

Comment: $y^\frac12\cdot y^\frac12$ is not $y^\frac14$.

Comment: @TonyK pointed out the main issue - You had it correct in the denominator for $y^{1/2}\cdot y^{1/2}$

Comment: Other than the arithmetic mistake already pointed out by the previous comments, your analytical approach is good.  The one possible improvement in your approach, for similar problems could be to start by letting (for example) $u = y^{(1/2)}$, evaluating the expression in terms of $u$, and then (at the end), convert the expression back into an expression in $y$, using (once again) $u = y^{(1/2)}.$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t=y^\frac12$ and you get:
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\frac{t}{t-2}+\frac{t}{t+2}-2= \\
&=\frac{t(t+2)+t(t-2)}{(t-2)(t+2)}-2=\\
&=\frac{t^2+2t+t^2-2t}{t^2-4}-2=\\
&=\frac{2t^2-2t^2+8}{t^2-4}=\\
&=\frac{8}{t^2-4}
\end{align}
Substitute back and you get:
$$\frac{8}{y-4}$$